# 'karthikpr'@'localhost' Error_log Mystery

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a mystery on my hands: initially I thought it was something unique but after googling it I see that it is happening to many other websites too.

In my root directory I keep getting a new error_log because of this error:

> [12-Jan-2015 13:18:35 America/Denver] SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'karthikpr'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

A new line appears every few minutes.

I am running MySQL, Apache, PHP, and have a Wordpress site in a subdirectory as a "knowledgebase". I have no idea how this wordpress site is designed.

The database is initialized in a config file behind the website root folder.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $hostname . ';dbname=' . $database . ';charset=utf8', $username, $password);
```

Anyone have an idea what this could be?

Comment: Google "Access denied for user 'karthikpr'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" o_O

Comment: Your site may be compromised. Not sure what that malware is attempting to do by accessing your database with hardcoded (and of course incorrect) credentials but anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone or more than likely just a script that targets websites looking for whatever it is that was found on your website is trying to access your server using the user 'karthikpr' and a faulty password.

Comment: Btw, if they attempt to obtain access over and over this can result in a denial of service, where you will not be able to log in even when using the correct credentials

Answer (score 0):

Update: Rather than wait for my database to be cracked, early in the morning when I had no real customer traffic, I matched up a date/time on my "latest vistors" list with the date/time in the error_log and found the offending IP address.

Then I added the following php script on the root index.php page:

```html
//BLOCK LIST OF IPs - CHECK PARTIAL MATCHES BY LEAVING OUT LAST PARTS OF IP
$blacklist = array("66.249.79.");

foreach ($blacklist as $key=>$value) {
 if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), strtolower($value)) !== false) {
  header("Location: http://www.1112.net/lastpage.html");
  exit();
 } 
}
```

And, for good measure, this in my .htaccess file in the root.

```html
order allow,deny
deny from 66.249.79.
allow from all
```

This seems to have done the trick.